# Swift basic int not convertible to ()

Tags: swift, recursion, int

So I just recently learned recursion in programming, and so I was trying to build a function in swift that returns the factorial of the value assigned.
just so you guys can get an idea, this is a code that does that but in Ruby.

```
def fat(num)
    if (num==1)
        return num
    else
        return num*fat(num-1)
    end
end
    p=gets.to_i
    x = fat(p)
    print ("#{x}")
```

I was trying to pretty much make the same code using swift but I realized there was an error right when I started coding

```
func fat (num: Int){
    if(num==1){
    return num
    }
}
```

It says line 3"int is not convertible to '()'"
so I don't really understand what's going on here...
I've looked up and because this language is so new I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
func fat (num: Int){
```

With this line

```
func fat (num: Int) -> Int {
```